# A system of linear equations in integer squares - solvable?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I consider this more a "recreational math" problem, possibly lacking a solution (because it stems from the question of "magic square of squares") or simply intractable with reasonable effort.

Consider the following matrix-equation in integers with otherwise arbitrary choosable values for $e,h,i$ only with the additional condition, that they must all be different, all must be odd, and more precisely, $e^2,h^2,i^2$ must be $1 \pmod {12}$
$$ \begin{array} {rcrrrr}
 \begin{bmatrix} a^2\\b^2\\c^2\\d^2\\f^2\\g^2 \end{bmatrix} & =&
 \left[ \begin{array} {rrr}
2 &  0 &   -1\\
2 & -1 &    0  \\
-1 & 1  &   1  \\
-2 & 1   &  2  \\
4 & -1    &-2  \\
3 & -1  &  -1  \\ \end{array} \right]  & \cdot \begin{bmatrix} e^2\\ h^2 \\ i^2 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{array} $$
Is it possible to find some $e,h,i$ with the given conditions, such that the lhs contains only squares? I thought, it might by possible by analysis of the coefficients matrix, but after some fiddling I didn't see a promising path... On the other hand, there might be some obvious(?) argument, that such a combination of squares is impossible. Or - that the given coefficients-matrix cannot -for some good reason- be of help for this problem.

[update] One could extend the conditions, such that we describe the unknowns $d^2,f^2,g^2$ as dependent on $a^2,b^2,c^2$ by the following further matrix equation
$$ \begin{array} {} 9 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} d^2\\f^2\\g^2\end{bmatrix}
&=&
  \left[ \begin{array} {rrr}
 -6 & 3 & 12 \\
 12 & 3 & -6 \\
 6 & 6 & -3
 \end{array} \right] \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a^2 \\ b^2 \\ c^2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
 $$

Comment: does $g$ have a scale factor of $3$ (or an odd number of them)? If not a simple parity of factors of $3$ would prove there is not a solution since each equation has a square on the left and a factor of $3$ on the right.

Comment: @adamW Well, at least the solution $a=\ldots=i=1$ is possible (except that the "must all be different" rules it out). Thus I guess that modulo observations cannot rule out the existence of a solution.

Comment: @adamW: I do not know more about the dependent variables than that they must be odd and congruent 1 (mod 12). However, it came to my mind in the afternoon that it is a field of old and intense research, how sums of squares can be equal ... hmmm...

Comment: by exhaustive search mod $12$ ( looking at squares it was only $64$ different cases) I see there is not a solution. I will type up my method for you now.

Comment: I must apologize as I calculated with an incorrect digit. Also, I have derived the exact same data as is in the question and thus verify its correctness. I am erasing my answer!